# Get values of clicked item in Arrayadapter list

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I am working on project which simply show `listview` that data come from the database.

I have used ArrayAdapter and AsyncTask to achieve this. My list is working but i need to get values of that particular list item when I clicked.

I have set database unique id to the `listviewitem` which I thought help to get id from the view, but I am stuck. I seen some video they got exact database id column of each list item which they clicking. But I have little knowledge in this concept.

My actual view is like this

[image]

This is my database operation class

```
    package com.me.doctor.doctor_me;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

    import com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper;

    public class DatabaseOperation extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

        public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DB_NAME= "app_db.db";

        public DatabaseOperation(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME,null, DB_VERSION);
        }

        // Verify user Loggin
        public boolean loginUser(String email, String password) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

            String sqlTables = "user";
            qb.setTables(sqlTables);

            Cursor c = qb.query(db,null,"email = ? AND password = ?",new String[]{email,password},null,null,null);

            if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Reg user
        public boolean registerUser(String user_name,String telephone,String nic,String gender,
                                    String email, String password){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

            contentValues.put("user_name", email);
            contentValues.put("telephone", telephone);
            contentValues.put("nic", nic);
            contentValues.put("gender", gender);
            contentValues.put("email", email);
            contentValues.put("password", password);

            long result = db.insert("user", null,contentValues);

            if(result == -1)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }

        // Get all infor from the doctor table to display in list view
        public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db){
            String[] selectios = {"d_id","d_name","d_hospital","d_category"};
            Cursor cursor = db.query("doctor",selectios,null,null,null,null,null);

            return cursor;
        }

    }
```

Doctor display class that is hold list view

```
 package com.me.doctor.doctor_me;

 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;

 public class DisplayDoctor extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_doctor_layout);
    BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
    backgroundTask.execute("get_info");
}

}
```

And this is AsynTask class

```
package com.me.doctor.doctor_me;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Doctor,String> {

Context ctx;
DoctorAdapter doctorAdapter;
Activity activity;
ListView listView;
Doctor doctor;

BackgroundTask(Context ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    activity = (Activity) ctx;
    doctor = new Doctor();
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    String method = strings[0];
    DatabaseOperation databaseOperation = new DatabaseOperation(ctx);
    if(method.equals("get_info")){
        listView = activity.findViewById(R.id.display_list_view);
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseOperation.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = databaseOperation.getInformation(db);
        doctorAdapter = new DoctorAdapter(ctx,R.layout.display_doctor_row);

        String name, category, hospital;
        int id;

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("d_id"));
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("d_name"));
            category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("d_category"));
            hospital = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("d_hospital"));
            Doctor doctor = new Doctor(id,name,category,hospital);
            publishProgress(doctor);
        }
        return "get_info";
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Doctor... values) {
    // add each of doctor class object add method inside the adapter class
    doctorAdapter.add(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    if(s.equals("get_info")){
        listView.setAdapter(doctorAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new  android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    final int position, long id) {

                // Stuck at here
            }
        });
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(ctx,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

This is the adapter class

```
package com.me.doctor.doctor_me;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DoctorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List list = new ArrayList();
public DoctorAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

// Add each object of doctor to the list object
public void add(@Nullable Doctor object) {
    list.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    DoctorHolder doctorHolder;

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.display_doctor_row,parent,false);

        doctorHolder = new DoctorHolder();
        doctorHolder.tx_name = row.findViewById(R.id.t_name);
        doctorHolder.tx_category = row.findViewById(R.id.t_category);
        doctorHolder.tx_hospital = row.findViewById(R.id.t_hospital);
        doctorHolder.tx_id = row.findViewById(R.id.t_id);
        row.setTag(doctorHolder);
    }else{
        doctorHolder = (DoctorHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Doctor doctor = (Doctor)getItem(position);
    doctorHolder.tx_id.setText(Integer.toString(doctor.getId()));
    doctorHolder.tx_name.setText(doctor.getName().toString());
    doctorHolder.tx_category.setText(doctor.getCategory().toString());
    doctorHolder.tx_hospital.setText(doctor.getHospital().toString());

    return row;
}
static class DoctorHolder{
    TextView tx_name, tx_category, tx_hospital, tx_id;
}
}
```

I think there is no need of attach XML because I already posted final view. If they required please let me know. I actually need to get each of clickable item database id column values, because using that id I have do more process in another activity.

Comment: Consider not using `SQliteAssetHelper` class. As it is not maintained anymore: More info: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: i am usinng SQliteAssetHelper class, but that will affect to archive this?

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal Your `setOnItemClickListener` is getting called or not?

Comment: yes its working, i have checked

Comment: No, It's okay to use but since it's not maintained now, it can be having unresolved issues later. **My Question** Where is your `setOnItemClickListener`?

Comment: It is in BackgroundTask class brother, can you see it?

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal Yes, I see it now, Thank you.

Comment: String var = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); i used that code, that show me some codes, which cannot understand.

Comment: Please take [the MVCE model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into account for your next questions.

Comment: i have provide all the required codes here.

Comment: Read the content of the link, answer after. That way, what you say will have a higher chance of making sense. For example, the link I provide talks about posting *as little as possible*, so you saying that you posted "all the codes" is the same as saying "I did it wrong". Unless you answered without reading the content, that is, which is a terrible habit to get into.

Comment: little as possible is depend on the problem, not for every case, i think you should understand it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new  android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                final int position, long id) {

           Doctor doctor = (Doctor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
           String ID = Integer.toString(doctor.getId());


        }
    });
```

Comment: let me check this code sir thank you for your effort. :)

Comment: editor show me error like "cannot resolve method getItem(int)"

Comment: Welcome update if any error..!

Comment: Try getItemAtPosition(position)..

Comment: finally you save me sir, update your code to last answer you gave me

Comment: and also i got a downvote too. what to do. i am new to this. any way respect you sir for helping each other. :)

Comment: Edited glad to help consider using [Recylerview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) in future coding it have plenty of feautures and updated widget..

Comment: I tried that too, this is urgent project they don't consider how i make it. in future surely i investigate this as much as i can, and make sure my self not get down ;)

Comment: Sure happy coding :)

Comment: sir can i open another activity using intent in this class? i think no, because this is BackgroundTask (Async Task) could you please give me an answer sir?

Answer (score 1):

**OnClickListener inside getView method**

```
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),doctor.getHospital().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
});
```

Hope this will help you......Have a nice day

Comment: sir, that show me two error like  "view cannot resolve symbol" and "Variable doctor is accessed within inner class, need to be declared final"

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal those errors are related to your lack of understanding of the *basics* of Java, such as variable visibility and being able to differentiate between variables and classes with the same name for this example. I *highly recommend* you start getting those before going forward in Android.

Comment: cool,let me ask something in code which i doesn't seen, in here i have not used doctor object either i'm not created. your prefer should i created it? and such like view is android concept not only the java.

Answer (score 0):

inside your `onBindViewHolder` you need to call OnClickListener

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          String name = list.get(position).getValueName();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Look at the code correctly. There is no `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: sir where is onBindViewHolder method?

Comment: inside your getView method, getView is your Viewholder

Comment: then sir you say i use this code inside getView method?